# Promises of jQuery Animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have an image moving to the right and once it finishes running an alert message pops up. I am using one of the jQuery promises *stop()* options to stop it before the animation gets completed. So far I could stop it with mouse *hover()* event. Here is how I did it

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var logoVar = $('#logo');

    logoVar.animate(
    {
        left: '600px'
    },
    {
        duration: 8000,
        done: function(){
            alert( 'animation is done!');
        }
    });

    $('#logo').hover(function(){ // hover over the animating image to stop it without letting it to get completed 
        logoVar.stop();
    });
});
```

Now I want to bind a couple mouse events like *mouseenter, mouseleave* instead of *hove()* to make sure that the animation is accurately responding to all mouse event handlers because I noticed that **Chrome** is responding late to ***hover()*** event and I can't stop it as I hover over the image. However, I checked using [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Durdona/v6zsk7j4/2/)  and get precise result. *hover()* works perfectly fine

I tried to use

```
.on('mouseenter mouseleave mouseup mousedown')
```

I guess I am not binding them correctly. Can someone give me any idea on that ? I would appreciate if I get the answer in complete

Using *on.()* here but there is no even errors on the console. The image is not moving either

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var logoVar = $('#logo');

    logoVar.animate(
    {
        left: '600px'
    },
    {
        duration: 8000,
        done: function(){
            alert('in animation done!');
        }
    });

    logoVar.on('mouseenter mouseleave')
    logoVar.stop();
});
```

Comment: Can you post the exact code you tried with `on()` and multiple events?

Comment: Well, you have to pass a handler function to `on()`, just as you did to `hover()`, instead of calling `stop()` after `on()`. You also have a typo in `mouseleave` in your new snippet.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi trying that one sec ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @FredericHamidy I found what was missing

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var logoVar = $('#logo');

    logoVar.animate(
    {
        left: '600px'
    },
    {
        duration: 8000,
        done: function(){
            alert('in animation done!');
        }
        });
        logoVar.on('mouseenter mouselease', function(){
        logoVar.stop(); 
    })  
});
```